# Error with CSV when trying install LaTeXStrings into Julia

Tags: julia

I am new to Julia simply trying to install LaTeXStrings with Julia v1.5.0.

```
using DataFrames
using CSV
using Pkg
using Plots
Pkg.add("LaTeXStrings")
using LaTeXStrings
```

but I get the following error

```
  Resolving package versions...
ERROR: LoadError: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package CSV [336ed68f]:
 CSV [336ed68f] log:
 ├─CSV [336ed68f] has no known versions!
 └─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement — no versions left
Stacktrace:
 [1] check_constraints(::Pkg.Resolve.Graph) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Resolve/graphtype.jl:935
 [2] Pkg.Resolve.Graph(::Dict{Base.UUID,Set{VersionNumber}}, ::Dict{Base.UUID,Dict{VersionNumber,Dict{String,Base.UUID}}}, ::Dict{Base.UUID,Dict{VersionNumber,Dict{String,Pkg.Types.VersionSpec}}}, ::Dict{Base.UUID,String}, ::Dict{Base.UUID,Pkg.Types.VersionSpec}, ::Dict{Base.UUID,Pkg.Resolve.Fixed}, ::Bool) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Resolve/graphtype.jl:362
 [3] deps_graph(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Dict{Base.UUID,String}, ::Dict{Base.UUID,Pkg.Types.VersionSpec}, ::Dict{Base.UUID,Pkg.Resolve.Fixed}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:495
 [4] resolve_versions!(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:367
 [5] targeted_resolve at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1107 [inlined]
 [6] tiered_resolve(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1093
 [7] _resolve at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1113 [inlined]
 [8] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}, ::Array{Base.UUID,1}; preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Linux) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1128
 [9] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}; preserve::Pkg.Types.PreserveLevel, platform::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.Linux, kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/API.jl:189
 [10] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/API.jl:140
 [11] #add#21 at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/API.jl:67 [inlined]
 [12] add at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/API.jl:67 [inlined]
 [13] #add#20 at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/API.jl:66 [inlined]
 [14] add at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/API.jl:66 [inlined]
 [15] add(::String; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/API.jl:65
 [16] add(::String) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/src/API.jl:65
 [17] top-level scope at /home/nick/mesa-r11701/star/test_suite/rsp_Cepheid_grid/CMD.jl:5
 [18] include(::Function, ::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:380
 [19] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:368
 [20] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:296
 [21] _start() at ./client.jl:506
```

What am I missing here? I already have CSV installed and it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such problems are usually caused by cluttering the current environment, or having old versions of several packages.
If you're using base environment, create a new one and install packages there by by

```
using Pkg
pkg"activate ."  # activates new environment
pkg"add DataFrames CSV Plots LaTeXStrings"  # adds all packages using handy macro
using DataFrames, CSV, Plots, LaTeXStrings
```

if it does not help, delete `Manifest.toml` and upgrade all your packages.
If it's successful, following versions should be installed

```
using Pkg
pkg"st"
  [336ed68f] CSV v0.7.7
  [a93c6f00] DataFrames v0.21.6
  [b964fa9f] LaTeXStrings v1.1.0
  [91a5bcdd] Plots v1.5.8
  [44cfe95a] Pkg
```

Also, if you already have clutterd the base environment, clean it up.
You can see it by

```
using Pkg
pkg"activate; st"
```

which prints list of packages installed in the base environment.

Comment: Hi, I removed all the packages from the base environment, deleted `Manifest.toml`, and tried to add the packages using the macro as you suggested, but I am still getting `ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package CSV [336ed68f]:
 CSV [336ed68f] log:
 ├─CSV [336ed68f] has no known versions!
 └─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement — no versions left
`

Comment: And just to be sure, what is the output of pkg"st"? Also, did the registry update for you during adding a package? Especially for long-running julia session it's noticable that registry update only the first time you add the package inside the single julia REPL session. 
So check the registry and if needed, you can delete the General registry locally and then restart Julia REPL, after trying to add package newest version of registry should be downloaded automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10, I followed these steps :

1. Open `C:\Users\user\.julia\registries`
2. Delete everything within this folder ( Don't worry they will be autocreated )
3. Open Julia terminal. At this point you should be at `julia>` prompt
4. Enter `]` and press enter. At this point you should be at `pkg` prompt
5. add CSV
6. To go back to julia prompt press Ctrl + C.

This will resolve the issue. Please note deleting registry folder contents means all previous packages will be deleted. You need to add all packages one by one. However it is worthy.